# WeChat Database Connectivity Issues

Tags: database, connectivity, wechat

This may sound like a real stupid question but I just can't seem to find the answer.

I've been playing with the WeChat Dev Tools. And I can see there is database - they call it Cloud Base.

What I want to know is ... is it possible to link that database to the outside world ?  Is it possible to import data into that database ?  I know WeChat is like a closed garden ... so can we get data in and out of this closed garden.

All input gratefully received.

Hugh

Comment: I found the documentation :
https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/wxcloud/reference-http-api/database/

It seems possible to export and import to a WeChat Cloudbase database just as normal webservices.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the database through http api,
please refer to this [link](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/wxcloud/reference-http-api/database/#Database).
it contains api like

- databaseMigrateImport
- databaseMigrateExport
- databaseMigrateQueryInfo
- databaseCollectionDelete
- databaseCollectionDelete
- databaseCollectionGet
- databaseAdd
- databaseDelete
- databaseQuery
- databaseQuery
- databaseCount